# How to pretty-print matrix to file through Logger output in Julia?

Tags: logging, julia, pretty-print

I want to log large matrices and I would like to log them in a way that makes them easily readable directly out of the resulting text file.  The most straight-forward way looks like using `Logger` but there are formatting difficulties.

If I log `randn(16,16)` to a file, I get this:

```
┌ Info: foobar
│   randn(16, 16) = [1.0942839407649314 -0.5527143448030067 0.8298165861408037 -0.629320299713892 2.18396754998307 0.6505983442819744 0.28478643396651215 0.49624898210542595 -0.3048986987119114 -2.503345301285143 1.5850964373263103 1.0690822749583955 1.536621653656582 -0.3607788383684874 0.885370044178199 2.041869532601766; -0.7377805500503828 -1.124408194854015 0.8328526306959119 -0.5572749807680694 0.6408054441740118 -0.6462048469289147 -0.9591927747206123 -0.5372908636704901 -1.5570243284212721 -0.005145593641188796 -0.5444781699058572 0.925543123863323 -1.7306550400632335 0.10537254071163348 -0.7464090795173964 -0.06846650882098887; 0.1261600543908416 -0.17564107393927636 0.37799797179302796 0.5515197435588174 0.34075149147447603 -0.7205246039791539 1.513614461546801 1.1642428600996686 -0.545674720151867 1.112236688886646 -0.47160248925370163 1.1571574283507013 -0.5958248573147353 0.5098298144780599 1.498566015181125 -0.5200142796044082; 0.16409174398919626 1.6310948018614768 -0.778140860677488 -0.4532609605747374 -0.7023742303864036 1.5401864216538148 -0.41055335411901517 -0.001664863626573417 1.7376977841607852 1.1438022489629136 -1.3092957173423554 0.2948158884473583 0.5442562158621472 0.29159148104627197 0.8456809667931658 0.3131211552957873; -0.18311435151215105 -1.146862513762513 2.9012387943560967 3.449013452598542 0.6687347461233634 0.07913713445145631 -0.05160779757757868 -0.9349833692218781 0.4717742965050141 -0.0181963649180495 1.1920714844977194 -0.8222935462660705 -0.08946288129248751 -2.0012644086753295 -1.2161550026599326 1.2740729475184585; -1.907234239729927 1.0349643916711275 0.7360485649937313 1.229025691714515 -2.78838670191124 1.6131641701309787 -0.2100355723095895 1.1388026659982902 2.3657788869803182 -1.2581841874126358 2.110945030243148 -0.03934074916008627 -0.9896003035015556 1.570995141867342 1.683891930601859 0.9233220086903396; -0.24948320231199203 1.6224116484951503 -0.2692553224552951 1.2062725093782347 -0.9979120311501751 -0.7386957829767121 -0.09356433134948755 -0.285603584516088 1.111109634735661 1.1186549170029494 -0.9666142121497854 -0.780938323449209 -0.5182378571486814 1.082269036245154 -1.1288251191361451 -2.022948167003981; -1.1181745876779214 -0.28154699704950803 2.329673013911238 -1.070010393730701 0.23681037850593975 -0.8487649777573679 -2.4710661410341883 0.42454291680403733 2.1447631730315653 0.014493586911904952 -0.07350663811995288 0.5834155317998089 0.7903769419759302 0.09960187318362655 0.8524749376121605 -1.0846042552903339; 0.4953735976250387 0.8377482188021276 0.5986099133227615 -1.202991430605467 -0.7767490048924991 0.19683276757481477 -1.616816307911441 -1.2444514305945498 1.127671917249609 0.41804665320578477 -0.09874387800647134 -0.902898437513548 0.046001410243378824 -0.07379997181897575 -0.23232215018142036 -0.10601662510961336; -0.5617475926199458 1.2562890444978514 0.3831877340263283 0.12723305377245117 -0.26919716826441226 2.002015044993809 0.37851557738558156 -1.5555354636810217 0.9768508047673141 0.7136052016973962 -0.08665670872895477 -0.974311324448916 1.3756817313919805 0.03827031627349298 -0.6062529944702241 -0.15246683765604255; -1.1380506489519269 -0.12423762049527971 2.4072042635204007 -1.313881261407342 -0.03479349667983464 -1.5576575527671341 0.40101804831672244 1.0921213247629291 -0.6183641287751859 -0.646623784521537 0.21553121731568947 -0.25323663446017186 -0.8956128988914726 0.18233240855051064 0.6193818398361657 0.5600771075913189; 0.7882637199585218 0.8003043354682213 -0.17984534089082396 0.17183686572553647 -1.0749613072592346 -1.2740675270300954 -0.44447448155177266 1.0558126362210882 -0.7685428475373318 -1.1055319296112538 -0.5765686647099925 -0.8385044506522431 0.24837765559546812 -0.11370676198739986 -0.6122739668173256 -0.08457045422390835; -0.027441064746724517 1.5621130031682404 -0.266112135975365 -0.191145168603357 0.4742294646655543 -0.331530501482253 0.269739822916295 0.6511151255542236 0.6105838269908159 -0.7038292841235069 -0.46427685792822126 0.044345335791929966 -0.5756692782537185 2.3359070275927265 -0.20749610649593905 0.07570251546947553; 0.8970897065951169 0.2335719986857013 0.6417453561045875 -1.111097433233705 -1.3224478854654598 -1.18361782192136 -1.1243730429859502 1.0836273900696147 -0.4588748896351182 0.3329886287863571 0.8195071139618756 0.8179634221575013 0.4063146363750835 0.9895897820036599 1.4243267718814585 -0.0920030383784131; -0.4711964468341074 0.29054697906206817 0.24330017814378666 -0.10583455998614952 -2.337695720705515 -0.04651175664518344 -0.712176216856488 0.3088026605762899 0.4326771923657886 0.1643295532833878 -0.9952671010013796 1.4880993990007374 -0.4340091532702065 -2.5950247016335366 -0.7299343132795931 -0.26620379703289365; 0.768544705433219 -1.5629938483332015 1.5004885493753322 -0.5640798524954589 0.06941235657881963 -1.6269702505581252 -1.3853883382909262 0.19387918264118958 1.5812313276947072 -1.9290986572150237 -0.4704774223033587 0.5010024141960878 0.5385026367654137 0.17302582420722679 1.448611605032558 -1.5582853299833432]
└ @ Main REPL[9]:1
```

Everything is dumped on one line.  Not easily readable.  If I `@info` to the REPL, I get this:

```
┌ Info: foobar
│   randn(16, 16) =
│    16×16 Matrix{Float64}:
│     -0.968584   0.945362  -0.803364  -0.730742   0.901276   0.327905   …  -1.01026    0.818471  -0.435231   0.0623963  -0.382759   1.85397
│     -0.23003    0.370287  -1.41081    0.681659  -0.951334  -0.838497      -1.10086    1.44219   -0.372032   0.455137    0.201996  -0.164303
│     -1.14103   -2.86561   -0.490761  -0.701454  -0.358823  -0.778483      -0.601529  -0.584301   0.737334  -0.616626   -0.519817  -0.130109
│      ⋮                                                      ⋮          ⋱   ⋮                                                       ⋮
│      1.92319    1.75182    1.11185    1.19387   -0.60792   -1.00847       -0.968184   0.740516  -1.57099   -0.0155163   0.737948  -2.09657
└      0.590805   0.894237  -0.129531  -1.04199   -0.995814   0.0523549  …  -0.868659   1.65477   -0.882401  -1.33365     0.933257   0.19146
```

It pretty-prints but skips rows and columns to fit the output on screen.

How do I make it output the matrix to a file in a grided format without skipping any elements?  I am aware that `@info`, `@debug` e.t.c. call `Base.show` and I could redefine it but I don't want to mess with general output functions and all their features.  Is there a way to make the Logger use a custom function instead of `Base.show`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not provide a minimal working example, however I understand that your problem is the following:

```
julia> Logging.@info randn(3,3)
[ Info: [1.0052088122181286 1.7088742688445533 0.5590861666231365; 0.7954478850977634 -0.16748800657090718 0.7328355145945802; -0.8932325909314845 -2.5159786957753907 -0.5405384234133582]
```

In that case try the following function:

```
function tostr(obj)
    io = IOBuffer()
    show(io, "text/plain", obj)
    String(take!(io))
end
```

And now you have:

```
julia> @info tostr(rand(3,3))
┌ Info: 3×3 Matrix{Float64}:
│  0.345996  0.46711   0.647508
│  0.661534  0.836607  0.0838559
└  0.512329  0.134263  0.287888
```

This will work no matter which packages you use for logging.